# Extract bullets from Word Document in R

Tags: r, text, text-extraction, officer, bulletedlist

I have a Microsoft Word document that contains several bullets and nested bullets (sub-bullets), with up to three levels of nesting.  I have been exploring the use of the `officer` package in R to read the text from the Word document, which I plan to then insert into a database.  I am able to successfully extract all the text from the document, but what I can't seem to figure out is how to extract the bullets themselves.  Each bullet and bullet level provides important contextual information about the text that I need to extract, but it seems the bullets are stripped/ignored using the `officer` package.  So my question is, is there any way for me to use `officer` to extract the bullets themselves, in addition to the text, or is there some other R package that I might be able to use that will retrieve the bullets as well?

I realize, I could probably write a custom function to extract the xml structure of the Word document and obtain the bullets from there, but I'm really trying to avoid digging into those details and re-creating the wheel that others might have already developed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, shortly after asking this question, I discovered the `docx_summary` function in `officer`.  It looks like this gets displays a column called level which indicates the bullet nesting level.  I think I should be able to use this to accomplish what I'm trying to do, so sorry, for answering my own question, but I figured this might be useful to others who are trying to do the same thing.  The only thing I really wish this had was the ability to determine exactly what symbol is used for the bullet, but I can work around that, but if others might know how to extract the symbol used at each bulleting level, that would be greatly appreciated.